# "I have no [...] anymore" - is it grammatically correct or not?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I just came across a sentence structure which I'm not entirely sure is grammatically correct, but I couldn't find anything searching the internet:

- "I have no [...] anymore."

My first instinct is that A) that sounds rather weird, especially with uncountable nouns, and B) this is wrong, it should be "I do not have any [...] anymore." But on second thoughts I'm not so sure, and now I've spent so long thinking about it I don't entirely trust my brain any longer. Is this construction actually incorrect, and why or why not?

Comment: I think the reason it sounds strange is that it's rather informal.  However, grammatically, it doesn't seem incorrect.

Comment: That's possible. It might be that it was the informality of this combined with "medication" rather than the informal "meds" that initially triggered my "this is wrong" reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to say *I have no dreams anymore*, or *I have no CDs anymore*. Uncountable nouns are fine too, as in *I have no water anymore*.

I cannot think of an object where it would sound wrong.

Comment: But doesn't _anymore_ use _not_? I've always thought it was _not anymore/longer_ and _no more/longer_, with of course a few exceptions (eg. "I want to spend not more than ten pounds", and even that would sound better to me with "no").

Comment: I think that's a different construction. _I used to do this -- not anymore!_ and _I no longer go to school_.